# Sort Array of strings on characters and return all matching elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects

```
var carList = [
    {
        car: "maruti",
        colors: ["red", "redish","yellow"]
    },
    {
        car: "ferrari",
        colors: ["purple", "red"]
    },
    {
        car: "Merc",
        colors: ["pink", "green"]
    }
];
```

Now I have an input search field where user can type the color of the car.
so if the user types red then only `maruti` and `ferrari` object should be returned.
and if user types reddish then only `maruti` object should be returned.

I tried using nested filter

```
var textToSearch = "re";  
var test = carList.filter((x) => x.colors.filter((y)=> y.indexOf("textToSearch") > -1) );
```

Even if the search string is of only 2 characters like "re" then also it should return maruti and ferrari as output.

but this returns all the objects not just maruti and ferrari

**Note**: I want that it should return all the matching elements and not just the first matching element.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var carList = [
    {
        car: "maruti",
        colors: ["red", "redish","yellow"]
    },
    {
        car: "ferrari",
        colors: ["purple", "red"]
    },
    {
        car: "Merc",
        colors: ["pink", "green"]
    }
];
var m = carList.filter((eachCar) => { 
    var colors = eachCar.colors;
    return colors.filter((eachColor) => {
           return eachColor.indexOf('in') !== -1
    }).length > 0;
});
                            
console.log(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in combination with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside the `filter()` to check if `textToSearch` exist in the `colors` array:

```
var textToSearch = "r";
var test = carList.filter(x => x.colors.some(cl => cl.includes(textToSearch)));
console.log(test);
```

```js
var carList = [{
    car: "maruti",
    colors: ["red", "redish", "yellow"]
  },
  {
    car: "ferrari",
    colors: ["purple", "red"]
  },
  {
    car: "Merc",
    colors: ["pink", "green"]
  }
];

var textToSearch = "re";
var test = carList.filter(x => x.colors.some(cl => cl.includes(textToSearch)));
console.log(test);
```

---

**Note:** You have to be carefully with this approach since `re` matches `green`!

---

*Based on comment:*

```js
var carList = [{
    car: "maruti",
    colors: ["red", "redish", "yellow"]
  },
  {
    car: "ferrari",
    colors: ["purple", "red"]
  },
  {
    car: "Merc",
    colors: ["pink", "green"]
  }
];

function getCars(event) {

  // Value of input field
  var value = event.target.name;
  
  // Sort carList
  var res = carList.filter(x => x.colors.some(cl => cl.includes(value)));
  
  // Show result to console
  console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<input onclick="getCars(event);" name="red" type="checkbox">red</input>
<input onclick="getCars(event);" name="llow" type="checkbox">llow</input>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply...but I want that Even if the search string is of only 2 characters like re then also it should return maruti and ferrari as output.
your answer only returns value when user type complete string as "red" and not "re".
Can  you pls modify your answer..

Comment: @Rakesh I've updated my answer. Tip for the next question; Take your time so all the parts of the questions are listed when you post it.

Comment: Thanks this is working fine. But had one more question.
Can I make this dynamic  (   carList.filter(({colors}) => )  I want that instead of hardcoded colors can i pass avariable from outside like the fieldName which was clicked by user. 
If user click on colors input field the filter array should filter on color if user clicks on cars input field the filter array should use cars object.
Is this possible or I have to write separate code for each field?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer thanks again for that...can you provide a small snippet of code for dynamically fetching the values instead of hard coded colors object.

Comment: @Rakesh I've added a small example, this should get you started. If you have any more questions regarding this implementation, you should open another question since this one has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

**Two problems:**

1. The function `filter` always returns an array, which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.
2. You have a typo on the variable `textToSearch` which is wrapped by double-quotes.

I recommend you to use the function `some` along with the function `includes` instead.

```js
let carList = [{    car: "maruti",    colors: ["red", "redish","yellow"]},{    car: "ferrari",    colors: ["purple", "red"]},{    car: "Merc",    colors: ["pink", "green"]}],
    textToSearch = "ed",
    fieldName = "colors",
    test = carList.filter((c) => c[fieldName].some(c => c.includes(textToSearch)));
    
console.log(test)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply...but I want that Even if the search string is of only 2 characters like re then also it should return maruti and ferrari as output.
your answer only returns value when user type complete string as "red" and not "re".
Can  you pls modify your answer..

Comment: Thanks this is working fine. But had one more question.
Can I make this dynamic  (   carList.filter(({colors}) => )  I want that instead of hardcoded colors can i pass avariable from outside like the fieldName which was clicked by user. 
If user click on colors input field the filter array should filter on color if user clicks on cars input field the filter array should use cars object.
Is this possible or I have to write separate code for each field?

Comment: Thanks a lot this perfectly works fine. I have up-voted your answer as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a late answer. But you can follow my `regex` solution.

Here I use [**RegExp.prototype.test()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method, with help of [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [**Array.prototype.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var carList = [{car: "maruti", colors: ["red", "redish","yellow"]}, {car: "ferrari", colors: ["purple", "red"]}, {car: "Merc", colors: ["pink", "green"]}];


const searchByColor = (list, keyword) => {
    // If you want the keyword must match from the beginning
    // const regex = new RegExp(`^${keyword}`, 'ig');
 
    // If you want the keyword matches anywhere of the string
    const regex = new RegExp(keyword, 'ig');
    return list.filter(({colors}) => colors.some(color => regex.test(color)));
}


console.log('For keyword "re":', searchByColor(carList, 're'));
console.log('For keyword "redish":', searchByColor(carList, 'redish'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

**Note:** notice that the color named `green` also has `re` substring. It's good to fetch as many relevant search results as you can.

But if you don't want to match anywhere of a string then use the commented first regex approach. That is use the `regex` as:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^${keyword}`, 'ig');
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeeb for your reply. I had 1 question In your answer the colors object in this line return list.filter(({colors}) => colors.some(color => regex.test(color))); is hard coded.
Can we write a function like searchByColor(listToBEFiltered, stringToSearch, ArrayName));
so that it is a dynamic function and not a hardcoded one..It would be great if you can provide a small template.

Comment: You mean not the `colors` array but any other array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter & `some`. Inside `filter` callback use some to get colors which includes the searched color

```js
var carList = [{
    car: "maruti",
    colors: ["red", "redish", "yellow"]
  },
  {
    car: "ferrari",
    colors: ["purple", "red"]
  },
  {
    car: "Merc",
    colors: ["pink", "green"]
  }
]

function getCar(color) {
  return carList.filter(item => item.colors.some(col => col.includes(color)))
}
console.log(' When it is red ', getCar('red'));
console.log('When it is redish', getCar('redish'));
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply...but I want that Even if the search string is of only 2 characters like re then also it should return maruti and ferrari as output.
your answer only returns value when user type complete string as "red" and not "re".
Can  you pls modify your answer..